# What is word for the logic error of no comparison when trying to argue for a comparison statement?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, when arguing "X is better than Y", one may argue in a way such that emphasizes "X is good" without mentioning Y, or "Y is bad" without mentioning "X", i.e., no actual comparison in the argument. What is the word for this logical error?

Comment: Does the sentence you're asking for mention both X and Y or just one of them? Because you say "X is good" or "Y is bad", just want a clarification.

Comment: @ChrisGong See my update.

Comment: An incomparable error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Wikipedia's [list of logical fallacies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fallacies):

> **Incomplete comparison** – in which insufficient information is provided to make a complete comparison.

Answer (score 1):

I'd call it an [incomplete comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_comparison). See also https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/faultycomp.htm.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't see you had edited your answer.

Comment: No sweat. - - -